# Why are release builds (android app) is debuggable in emulator even when debuggable is set false

Tags: android, android-emulator

Thank you for help in advance. I want to know why are release app are debuggable when they are run in emulator even when debuggable is set to false. I tried WhatsApp app in emulator, it was able to show me the logs.
Can anyone tell me the reason for this.? Please ignore my bad English.

Comment: app is not debuggable does not mean that it does not log anything. That 2 things are different

Comment: But I'm able to attach the debugger to a release build which is not debuggable.